# New batch file format / commands?

Tags: batch-file

Last time I used batch files, I learned with examples from an MSDOS 5.0 book.
Now, while trying to apply a command on all files in a directory, I stumbled upon

```
for %%J in (*.exe *.dll) do @echo %%J
```

I thought "this can't be a batch file", but yet it works.

Q1: How is this new format called and/or where do I find a list of things I can do with this new format?

Q2: (*.exe *.dll) is not a DOS-style command; so what is it?

Q3: How do I modify this "command" to include files in all subdirectories?

Comment: The command you listed works in MSDOS V5 too, without the @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Informally, NT batch. Oficially, who cares?
2. Certainly is dos-style. * has always meant `matches anything` Perhaps not in a `FOR` command, but that's NT batch for you. Enhancements, see?
3. Look at

   FOR /?

from the prompt.

Or generally

*commandname* /?

Or go to `Help & Support` and look for `command line`

Answer (score 0):

It is a DOS style command. [The format of `for-loop`](http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm) in DOS:

> FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

`(*.exe *.dll)` is the set in the for command, it means all files with exe and dll extensions.
`*` is the wildcard character.

So this command will echo the names of all exe and dll files in the current directory.

You can use following for-loop to include files in all subdirectories:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims==" %%d in ('dir /s /b /o:gn *.exe *.dll') DO ( 
  ECHO %%d
)
```

Comment: Excuse me. This is _NOT_ Delayed Expansion. Your program will work removing `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command and there is not a single variable enclosed in exclamation marks here! Please, don't confuse the beginner even more...